# Tiny scrollbar doesn't work with javascript (javascript conflict)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scrollbar

I'm using [tiny scrollbar](http://www.baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/) for my new website www.digimobjobs.com
I'm using this scrollbar in many places, but this webste is the only place that has a scrollbar problem.
This is where: http://www.digimobjobs.com/news.php.

At the twitter tab and news tab, I have to put a specific scroll height:

```
#newsWidget
{
    font-weight:lighter;
    font-size:12px; 
    height:2000px;
    color:#333333;
    text-align:left;
}

#twitter-ticker{
    width:610px;
/*  height:921px; */
height:1025px;
    color:#4297f9;
/*  display:none; */
    text-align:left;
}
```

In the rest of the places I'm using the same code of the tiny scrollbar. I think the conflict is between javascript. Actually I don't have enough knowledge of javascript.
Could any one help me please? If you use firebug you can see my entire code.
Please help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tested your site with Google Chrome and Firefox and I <strike>don't</strike> see <strike>any</strike> problem.

---

### Extra

However, if you are still having problems on yours, you might want to consider changing  the scrollbar using CSS3.

Learn more:

- [Surfin' Safari Blog](http://www.webkit.org/blog/363/styling-scrollbars/) (harder to understand)
- [CSS-Tricks*](http://css-tricks.com/9130-custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/) (easier to understand)

In conclusion, it is basically working like this: (From the CSS-Tricks site)

```
::-webkit-scrollbar              { /* CSS here */ }  /*the whole scrollbar*/
::-webkit-scrollbar-button       { /* CSS here */ }  /*the scrollbar buttons*/
::-webkit-scrollbar-track        { /* CSS here */ }  /*the scrollbar's whole track*/
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece  { /* CSS here */ }  /*the scrollbar's track*/
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb        { /* CSS here */ }  /*the scrollbar's moving piece*/
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner       { /* CSS here */ }  /*bottom corner piece (when no resize)*/
::-webkit-resizer                { /* CSS here */ }  /*bottom corner piece (when there's resizing)*/
```

---

### Update

I have done a few testing, and I fixed the second tab:

```
// Try running this in the console when it the page is completely loaded.
$("#news_feed").tinyscrollbar();
$("#news_feed").tinyscrollbar_update();
```

According to the *Tiny Scrollbar* site, it said,

> The update (*`.tinyscrollbar_update()`*) method can be used for adjusting a scrollbar to its new content.

So you will have to call it every time you change the content. For example, your XML updating needs to call it every time.

**But why the problem is happening?**
After a few testing, it seems like the `api` runs before your content is loaded.
As a result, it thought that the two `<div>`s are empty and has no height (so no scrollbar for you).

**The first Twitter tab?**
Try to fix it by yourself.

I have never used this plugin before, so I might be wrong. Fix me if you see a mistake.

Comment: thank you very much to check my code and everything 

In http://www.digimobjobs.com/news.php I just put height manually.

I just hosted http://athimannil.com/mobjob/news.php 
there the height is blank like other tabs Digitalevents, Testimoniial...etc
`
`    #twitter-ticker{
     width:610px;
 display:none; */
     text-align:left;
    }

    #newsWidget
    {
     font-weight:lighter;
     font-size:12px; 
     color:#333333;
     text-align:left;
    }`
`
you can realize what problem I'm facing 

I'm very happy to considering my problem 
please help me

Comment: Then why don't you just put in a specific height (by javascript or CSS) before jQuery is loaded?

Comment: I'm really really happy for ur research
I'm not good in javascript
could you tell me that Where should I type `tinyscrollbar_update()`

I'm keep on trying to fix twitter tab

Comment: You should put those two lines in a callback function of your News Widget plugin, but it looks like your News Widget plugin does not support callback function... D:

Comment: @maanu, Maybe you should update the `<div>` when the tab is pressed. Good luck. And you can choose my answer as the `chosen answer`.

Comment: I have just copied like this `$("#twitter_scroll").tinyscrollbar_update();
    $("#news_feed").tinyscrollbar_update();
`
it's working. But the problem is that. 
which tabe is open while loading that one working fine rest couldn't working. 
here is the link [link]http://athimannil.com/mobjob/test/news.php

Comment: I found call back on both plugin. working based on which one loading last :(

Comment: @maanu, call `$("#news_feed").tinyscrollbar();` also.

Comment: Let me try 
I'm so happy for ur support :)

Comment: By the way, you can select my answer as the "Selected answer".

Answer (score 0):

Please Re Init tinyScroller bar by this mathod.

$('#scrollbar1').tinyscrollbar_update();